# Yarn commands in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, yarnpkg

I have used the below to build the code using yarn , which was perfectly working in Azure DevOps pipeline until yesterday

[image]

I am not sure what has changed, now its throwing the below error:

[image]

I have searched the error for exit code 127 but the solution is removing node_modules folder and rerunning. But this cannot be achieved in build agent.
Any solutions that can be applied in this situation?

Update:

I used system.debug=true and below is the output:
[image]

Comment: Did you try the command under your local agent, is that right? And if that failed, what is the specific error? Also, you could use `system.debug= true` under pipeline to check the error.

Comment: the command failed in the self hosted agent , but it was working a day before. When that failed, it showed "yarn :command not found".  In my local system when I tried it was working fine. In Azure pipelines it is failing ( which was working earlier)

Comment: I have updated the query with the screenshot after using system.debug=true

Comment: same problem here :(

Answer (score 3):

I found what was changed here overnight, InfraAdmin has changed microsoft hosted agent to self hosted agent , which didnt have yarn dependencies installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `corepack enable` to the top of your command line script. That worked for me when I was getting the same error message.